# There is not any thing / There are not any things

Tags: sentence-construction

I know I can use any + plural like followings.

> 1. There are not any movies playing on Christmas day.
> 2. There are no movies playing on Christmas day.

Then how about these sentences?

> 3. There is not any thing that I can do at home. ( I know it is possible)
> 4. There are not any things that I can do at home.
> 5. There are no things that I can do at home.
> 6. There are nothing that I can do at home.

Answer (score 2):

In 3, "any thing" should be replaced with the word "anything".

4 and 5 are grammatically correct but sound awkward.

In 6, "are" should be replaced with "is". After that replacement, it would be the most natural way for native speakers to say it.

Comment: Also, in 6, no *that* is required especially in speech. - There's nothing I can do at home.